# powershell exchange 2003 : wmi-object does not pull all mailbox stores?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have the following code pulling from my exchange server 2003.

```
     connect-qadservice -service 'localhost'    
foreach ($server in $exchangeservers)
    {
    $AllUsers += get-wmiobject -class Exchange_Mailbox -namespace Root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -computername $server| select servername,storagegroupname, storename,mailboxdisplayname,totalitems,size, DeletedMessageSizeExtended, legacyDN, datediscoveredabsentInDS
    }
 $exchngver = "2003"

foreach ($user in $AllUsers)
{
  $obj = new-object psObject
  $office = get-qaduser -Identity $user.legacyDN | select office, description
}
disconnect-qadservice
```

and it doesn't grab all the mailbox stores on the server.  Any idea why or what might be causing this?

thanks in advance

NOTE: IT seems to grab all the mailbox stores except for 1 in the 2nd storage group.  I have no idea why this is...  The funny thing is my vbscript grabs all the mailbox stores using the same namespace and class just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So to start simple, does it come back correct before you unroll & start using the quest stuff?

Do you get the right number from:

```
(get-wmiobject -class Exchange_Mailbox -namespace Root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -computername srv02).count
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things (not sure they are the cause (#1)):

1. you are looping over `$exchangeservers` but don't use `$server` in `-computerName` (there's a fixed "srv02" server name).
2. I would move the `connect-qadservice -service 'localhost'` out of the `foreach` servers loop (You call it for each server in exchangeservers).
3. You are calling `get-qaduser` twice (`$tmp` and `$office`) to get the user office and description, you can do it in one call (`$tmo` is redundant):

Comment: i updated that much however it seems it still overlooking one of the storagegroups.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked permissions on the Stores/SGs?